# App Transport Security and watchOS1 issue

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, app-transport-security

Back in the days i've designed the Watch app for the **watchOS1**.
Now i've updated **Xcode** to 7.0.1 and because the original app tries to access backend server (which is not https) i had to add some rules for the **AppTransport Security** to the **Info.plist** file. The original app works fine, but i've encountered a critical issue with the watchKit app - it simply doesn't load.

The thing is - the watchKit app also performs a simple **http-json** request and connects to the server. The debugger shows the following log when i try to run it:

> [8210:461000] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP
>   (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can
>   be configured via your app's Info.plist file. [8210:460900] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

I cannot add **App Transport Security** changes to plist of the Watch app because it automatically changes the deployment target to **watchOS2** and crashes the whole project (it's build on `openParentApplication` method).

All in all, i can't access the server because **AppTransport** doesn't allow it, i cannot add a rule for **AppTransport**, because it's not supported by **watchOS1** - so i was wondering if there could be any other workarounds not requiring the radical change of code?

Thank you.

Comment: there are two different errors in this log. The first one asks for ATS itself, but the reason of not loading watch is second line. "[8210:460900] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'".

Comment: info.plists are text files.  Did you try editing the file by hand using a text editor like BBEdit to add the ATS keys?